# how to create context menu in statusbar?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have some problems
1. how do I make my statusbar context menu that consists of 2 choices of menu preferences and addons status

example of context menu i want to make

[image]

this is my code :

```
<popupset>
  <menupopup id="intransContextMenu">
    <menuitem label="intrans aktif"/>
    <menuitem label="preferensi"/>
  </menupopup>
</popupset>

     <statusbar id="status-bar">
          <image src="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png" />
          <statusbarpanel id="status-bar-intrans"
           label="intrans"
           context="intransContextMenu"
           onclick="alert('okeh cuy')"
       tooltiptext="intrans versi 1.0"
       />
    </statusbar>
```

2. how to add images in the context menu? I have tried but why do I paste a picture that always appears under the label is not on the side of the label as I expected?

example of context menu i want to make [image]

this is my code :

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
      <image src="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png" />
        <menuitem class="inlinetrans" id="inlineContext" oncommand= "hadits_mean.startFind(null);"
        label="Cari Terjemahan"/>
    </popup>
```

**note :**
whether the code used to display the menu by right clicking on the statusbar and allows web pages to be made in one file?

thank you for the answer..

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the images are your only problem now? Opening the context menu should work (you are using the [`context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/context) attribute correctly).

Regarding images, have a look at the documentation. For [`statusbarpanel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel), you have to set the [`image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel#a-image) attribute:

```
<statusbar id="status-bar">
      <statusbarpanel id="status-bar-intrans"
           image="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png"
           label="intrans"
           context="intransContextMenu"
           onclick="alert('okeh cuy')"
           tooltiptext="intrans versi 1.0"
      />
</statusbar>
```

You might also want to have a look at the [style classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel#Style_classes) and play with them (to be honest I'm not 100% sure if it is just sufficient to set the `image` attribute, so if this does not work, try with the style classes).

Similar for the [menuitem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menuitem). You have to set the [`image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menuitem#a-image) attribute **and** give the element the [style class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menuitem#Style_classes) `menu-iconic`:

```
<menuitem class="inlinetrans menu-iconic" 
          id="inlineContext" 
          oncommand= "hadits_mean.startFind(null);"
          label="Cari Terjemahan"
          image="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png"/>
```

---

**Note:** Afaik the statusbar is going to be removed in Firefox 4 (at least by default it is disabled)!